# How to Response correctly for Current request is not a multipart request in REST

Tags: java, spring, http, servlets, multipartform-data

I have created a simple REST endpoint that the client can post with a multipart form data using Spring Boot. The REST endpoint accepts a txt file and performs necessary function. But when the request is not valid or incorrect I cannot return proper HTTP response.

My controller looks like

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/create", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String create(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
    if (!file.isEmpty()) {  
        //perform some steps        
        return "file succesfully creted!";
    }else{
        logger.warn("file is empty");
        return "file wrong";
    }
}
```

I want the REST to correctly send proper HTTP response and status by using ResponseEntity. Now when the client makes a request

```
curl -X POST localhost:8080:/create -F "file=@sample.txt"
```

With this request everything works proper. Now lets say the user fails to attach a file or any other incorrect request I am not able to capture it. It goes into dispatcher servlet and it throws an error.

```
{
  "timestamp": 1474236317572,
  "status": 500,
  "error": "Internal Server Error",
  "exception": "org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException",
  "message": "Current request is not a multipart request",
  "path": "/create"
}
```

How do i take this error and send it back to the user. Should I have a filter ? How should I write this filter ? Or should there be a try/catch ?

Comment: I'm new to spring but I believe you can write an exception handler in your controller to handle the MultipartException.  When the exception is thrown the handler method in the controller will execute.  Here is alinke that might help.https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the exception with an @ExceptionHandler method like below.

```
@ExceptionHandler(MultipartException.class)
public ResponseEntity<String> handleMultipartException(HttpServletRequest request, Exception e) {
    return new ResponseEntity<>("Error: " + e.getMessage(), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
}
```

When spring tries to resolve the MultipartFile and can't, the exception is thrown and the appropriated annotated method for that exeception will be ran.

EDIT: Here are a couple of resources that might be useful.

https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oG2rotiGr90